# popStackImmediate() Causing illegal state exception

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

This is the code

```
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    int count = fm.getBackStackEntryCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        fm.popBackStackImmediate();
    }
```

This code works normally in all cases. But we are getting illegal state exception when this invoked from a broadcast receiver.

Sharing the logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run 
  (LoadedApk.java:894)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5484)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
  (ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss 
  (FragmentManager.java:1842)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate 
  (FragmentManager.java:775)
  at com.app.sample.BaseContentFragmentHolderActivity.startFragment 
  (BaseContentFragmentHolderActivity.java:58)
  at app.sample.SampleActivity.showDashboardFragment 
  (SampleActivity.java:732)
  at com.app.sample.SampleActivity.onMotionDetected 
  (SampleActivity.java:725)
  at com.app.sample.SampleActivity$3.onReceive 
  (SampleActivity.java:261)
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run 
  (LoadedApk.java:884)
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: @AbhayBohra : Shared the logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception rises if the app is in the background. Implemented logic to make sure that app is in foreground on executing these code.